# can't install rails 4.2.10 with source "http://rubygems.org" getting forbidden error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

While installing

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.10 --source https://rubygems.org
```

on mac monterey getting error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
bad response Forbidden 403 (http://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/nokogiri-1.13.1-x64-unknown.gemspec.rz)
```

Comment: What version of a Ruby do you use? Are you in an Intel or M1 Mac?

Comment: It's M1 Mac, I am using ruby `2.5.9`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. M1 Mac, while setting up to run Ruby 2.5.1 and an older Rails app.

I followed these steps from a Github comment:

```
gem update --system
xcode-select --install (didn't need to do this, though it was a listed step)
gem install nokogiri
bundle install
```